# Error While Cloning Products with Opportunity through Apex

Tags: apex, opportunity-lineitem, clone, debug

I'm getting following error: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject

Please find the code:

```
//Clone Products Related With Opportunity 
            OpportunityLineItem oppLineItemCloneRecord = new OpportunityLineItem(); 
            List<OpportunityLineItem> oppLineItemList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>(); 
            
            PricebookEntry pricebookEntryRecord = [SELECT Id, Name, Pricebook2Id From PricebookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id  = :opportunityRecord.Pricebook2Id]; 
            
            for(Opportunity opportunityObject: [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name, Quantity, TotalPrice FROM OpportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :recordId])
            {
                for(OpportunityLineItem oppLineItemObject: opportunityObject.OpportunityLineItems)
                {
                    oppLineItemCloneRecord = oppLineItemObject.clone(false, true, false, false); 
                    oppLineItemCloneRecord.Clone_Opportunity_Product_Name__c = 'Clone-' + oppLineItemObject; 
                    oppLineItemCloneRecord.OpportunityId = opportunityCloneRecord.Id; 
                    oppLineItemCloneRecord.Parent_Opportunity_Product__c = oppLineItemObject.Id;
                    oppLineItemCloneRecord.Child_Cloned_Opportunity_Product__c = true;
                    oppLineItemCloneRecord.Quantity = oppLineItemObject.Quantity;
                    oppLineItemCloneRecord.TotalPrice = oppLineItemObject.TotalPrice;
                    oppLineItemCloneRecord.PricebookEntryId =  pricebookEntryRecord.Id;
                    
                    System.debug('oppLineItemCloneRecord----->' + oppLineItemCloneRecord);
                    
                    oppLineItemList.add(oppLineItemCloneRecord); 
                    
                    System.debug('oppLineItemList----->' + oppLineItemList);
                }
                
                insert oppLineItemList; 
            }
```

Could anyone suggest where I'm doing wrong. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, the error message is giving you a good hint here.

SOQL queries *always* return a `List<SObject>`. Even if the query results in 0 rows being returned, it'll be a `List<SObject>`. An empty list, but still a list nonetheless.

Salesforce allows us to assign the result of a query to a single SObject instance as "syntactic sugar", a quality-of-life thing that reduces how much we need to type, but it only works ***when your query returns a single row***. Since you have more than one `PricebookEntry` in your `Pricebook2`, you would either need to store the result of the query in a `List<PricebookEntry>`, or add `LIMIT 1` to the query.

Honestly though, you don't need the query on `PricebookEntry` for what you're attempting to do here. Just include `PricebookEntryId` in your subquery on the `for(Opportunity opportunityObject: [SELECT Id...]){` line, and you'll be able to clone that data.

Other notes:

- Don't perform DML inside of a loop. Move the `insert oppLineItemList;` outside of all loops. Otherwise, you'll attempt to re-insert OLIs for a previous Opp if you're working with more than one opp. Even if you are only working with a single Opp, *don't get in the habit of putting queries or DML inside of loops*.
- `oppLineItemCloneRecord.Clone_Opportunity_Product_Name__c = 'Clone-' + oppLineItemObject;` is incomplete. `oppLineItemObject` isn't a string, it's an `SObject`. You want `oppLineItemObject.Name;` here
- `opportunityCloneRecord` isn't defined anywhere in the code you've provided, so either eliminate this line (if you're just cloning an OLI and not trying to clone the Opp as well) or make sure that this variable is defined (and has an Id)

Comment: Thank you @Derek F for your time and reply. It is extremely helpful. 
Thank you so much for providing detailed explanation.